# Error while joining two tables to create a new table in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to join two tables (utopia_users and utopia_user_activity) to create a new table and I am using the below code. I have tried putting lines 2 - 4 in brackets, but this did not solve the problem.

```
CREATE TABLE new AS
    SELECT *
    FROM utopia_users
    FULL JOIN utopia_user_activity 
        ON utopia_users.id = utopia_user_activity.user_id;
```

I am receiving the below error and do not understand why this is.

````
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. Incorrect syntax near ')'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298201/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-select-incorrect-syntax-near)

Comment: Why not create a view instead?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Is new the table you're trying to apply ? If so, it won't work given that new is reserved in SQL. You must change it to something lese

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)